# How to launch SQL Server Management Studio on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I just installed SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows 7. Now I want to launch the program that will allow me to create database, tables,... through Management Studio. But I don't find any icon after the installation that would help me to do that the Icon a found are just:

- SQL Server Installation Center
- Server configuration manager
- SQL Server Error and usage...
- Server Installation Center

Please notice that I'm new in SQL Server and I just want to setup a basic environment in order to make connection to a program.

Comment: Looks like you need to install SQL Server Management Studio.  This can be located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Once installed point it to the SQL Express instance you created.  For instance: `LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: There are different "packages" of SQL Server Express - the Management Studio is included in the SQL Server Express **with Tools** or the SQL Server Express **Advanced Services** packages only. If you didn't install one of these, either remove the current one and use one of these, or download and install Management Studio separately

Comment: I don't understand why the download page does not specify such important information ... even why some one will download the DBMS without the package that help him to interact with it ( though it should be by default included ! )

Comment: If you go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299 and click on "Details"; it pretty clearly and concisely shows and explains which parts are included in which package - or which are not.

Comment: Thank to all of you ! the solution of marc_s helped me ...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/ms190699(v=sql.105).aspx

It is a step-by-step guide on how to launch instances of either the default or name server. If you would prefer a video guide, you can check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PJXFcRPKFc

Comment: Please I dont want to launch instances only but a graphical program that help me to interact with the DBMS ...