# Installing SQL Management Studio (IDE) for Windows 7

Tags: ssms

After years of programming, it's a shame for me to ask such a question, but the fact is that I can't set up MS SQL Management Studio IDE for Windows 7. I've tried running all possible exe files from the [official site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx), but I still can't get the **IDE** per se. I mean, all I succeed to do, is just to install the Server itself. Also, I've tried to download a SSMS file, but after clicking the installation file, nothing happens. And when I say nothing, I mean really nothing.
Other installation files say that I can't install this version for my system. 
I have Windows 7 64 bit on my notebook. 
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201626/how-to-launch-sql-server-management-studio-on-windows-7) states the same problem, but I wasn't able to solve the issue following the steps described in the answer.
I guess, the problem is that I choose incorrect version. Maybe it must be 2008 instead of 2012. I am lost and need help on this.

Comment: Strange. Downloaded version 16.5.1 from the first link you provided and it started a setup and is now downloading packages...

Comment: is your OS Windows 7 64 bit ?

Comment: Yes. It is installing now. And I do have SQL2005, SQL2008 and SQL2014 Express installed already.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS is now supported independent of the SQL installation.  As of v16, it is maintained independently and claims backwards compatibility to SQL2008.  The latest version is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

As of this post, SSMS v17.9.1 worked on my installation of Windows 7 Pro x64 and allowed me to connect to a remote SQL2017 instance.

SSMS version 17.x or later does not support connecting to the legacy SQL Server Integration Services service. To connect to an earlier version of the legacy Integration Services, use the version of SSMS aligned with the version of SQL Server.